# Xamarin render child views on top of costume view

Tags: xamarin.forms

I created a MapView with SkiaSharp which renders a map on the full canvas.

```cs
public class MapView : SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKCanvasView
{
        protected override void OnPaintSurface(SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
        {
                //Code...
        }
}
```

To control the map and to give informations to the user. I want to render buttons, labels etc. on top of my MapView.
Preferably like this:

```xml
<VUK:MapView x:Name="vukMapView"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
    <StackLayout>
        <Button></Button>
        <Image></Image>
        <Label></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</VUK:MapView>
```

I get that `SKCanvasView` can't handle the content. But how can i solve it the most easy way?

Comment: use layout container - grid, absolutelayout, etc - and place one view on top of the other

Comment: @Jason is correct. XF has an assumed Z-Index based on order of the XAML. Z-Index is established by the ordering of the Child elements in a container element. The first child is at the back of the Z stack, the second child is placed above it, and so on.